# C# Android sqlite database

Tags: c#, android, sqlite

I am trying to create a SQLite database in C# Android:

```
public void CreateDatabase (string sDatabaseName)
        {
            try {
                sMessage = "";
                string sLocation = System.Environment.GetFolderPath
    (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string sDB = Path.Combine (sLocation, sDatabaseName);
                bool bIsExists = File.Exists (sDB);     
                if (!bIsExists) {
                    sqldTemp = SQLiteDatabase.OpenOrCreateDatabase (sDB, null);
                    sSQLQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                         "MyTable " +
                        "(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Name VARCHAR,Age    
INT,Country VARCHAR);";
                     sqldTemp.ExecSQL (sSQLQuery);
                    sMessage = "New database is created.";
                } else {
                    sqldTemp = SQLiteDatabase.OpenDatabase (sDB, null, 
DatabaseOpenFlags.OpenReadwrite);
                    sMessage = "Database is opened.";
                }
                bDBIsAvailable = true;
            } catch (SQLiteException ex) {
                sMessage = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

My questions are:

1) What does

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath
        (System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) mean?
```

2) Where can I find the db file? sdcard?

I search the db file, but i failed. I thought it should be in sdcard of device. However, I could not find it. I would appreciate if anyone can help out.

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal Xamarin? )

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal The correct answer to your question is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

On 1): It returns the path of the Personal folder folder. You could use a `Toast` to output that path so you can see what it is.

On 2): If you output the path as I suggested above you know where to look for your database file, as the folder is used to created the database file in.

Basically the code say:

1. Get the folder of one of the standard folders as defined in the `SpecialFolder` enum
2. Check whether our database file exists in this folder
3. If not, create it there